# Response from Retrofit can't get object value

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

> {   "StatusCode": 200,   "StatusDescription": "OK",   "ErrorMessage":
>   "",   "ErrorDetail": "",   "Results": [
>       {
>         "Key": "AccessTokens",
>         "Value": "[{\"Key\":\"XXXXX",
>         \"Value\":\"BABABA\"},{\"Key\":\"DIDADIDA\",\"Value\":\"YYYYY"
>       }   ]"}]}

This is the response i will get when i success call the API. The datatype of "Results" is List. Can anyone explain for me how to get the "Key" and the "Value".

My Object Classes

```
public class KeyValueItem {

    private String Key;
    private String Value;

    public String getKey() {
        return Key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        Key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Response Class

```
public class RestServiceResponse {

    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    @Expose
    public int StatusCode;
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return StatusCode;
    }


    @SerializedName("StatusDescription")
    @Expose
    public String StatusDescription;
    public String getStatusDescription() {
        return StatusDescription;
    }


    @SerializedName("ErrorMessage")
    @Expose
    public String ErrorMessage;
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }


    @SerializedName("ErrorDetail")
    @Expose
    public String ErrorDetail;
    public String getErrorDetail() {
        return ErrorDetail;
    }


    @SerializedName("Results")
    @Expose
    public List<KeyValueItem> Results;
    public List<KeyValueItem> getResults() {
        return Results;
    }

}
```

Anyone help please =(

Some of my code:

```
public void onResponse(Call<RestServiceResponse> call, Response<RestServiceResponse> response) {

                    Log.i("ddsddsadsa", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    RestServiceResponse restServiceResponse = response.body();
                    if(restServiceResponse.getStatusCode() == 200){
                        List<KeyValueItem> list = response.body().getResults();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
                        try {
                            JSONObject job = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
                            String testttt = job.getString("Key");
                            Log.i("dsadsadsadas", testttt);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Please post properly formatted JSON response. The one you posted gives an error in JSON validator

Comment: @prashant17 Maybe when i try to edit the original one and makes mistakes. BTW the JSON return is kind of weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things you have to understand first.

1. Your JSON data is not in valid format. It contains `\` (slashes) to escape double quotes in key-value pair. To confirm whether the returned JSON data is valid or not please copy & paste your JSON response into [JSON validator and Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Maybe problem in server script.
2. If you're using `GsonConvertorFactory` with Retrofit, Retrofit will automatically converts JSON response data to POJO internally. So, you don't need parse it again inside `onResponse()` method. If you get proper JSON response from server side then use it like below.

   ```
   public void onResponse(Call<RestServiceResponse> call, Response<RestServiceResponse> response) {

               // code....
               RestServiceResponse restServiceResponse = response.body();

               if (restServiceResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {

                   List<KeyValueItem> list = response.body().getResults();

                   for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        KeyValueItem kvi = list.get(i);
                        // do whatever you want with kvi object
                   }
               }
   }
   ```

Comment: This works too. But i have solve my answer. Take a look at below? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onResponse(Call<RestServiceResponse> call, Response<RestServiceResponse> response) {

                    Log.i("ddsddsadsa", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    RestServiceResponse restServiceResponse = response.body();
                    if(restServiceResponse.getStatusCode() == 200){


                        List<KeyValueItem> list = response.body().getResults();
                        for(KeyValueItem keyValueItem : list) {
                            String key = keyValueItem.getKey();
                            String value = keyValueItem.getValue();

                            Log.i("Keykeykey", key);
                        }

                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(value);
                                for(int i = 0; i <  jsonArray.length();i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String keykey = obj.getString("Key");
                                    String VAlll = obj.getString("Value");
                                    Log.i("c1111",keykey);
                                    Log.i("c222222", VAlll);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }


                    }else if(restServiceResponse.getErrorMessage() != null){
                        builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Error");
                        builder.setMessage(restServiceResponse.getErrorMessage());
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",null);
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
```

OK. Btw. i have try this to get my result. and it works!
To answer those about a invalid JSON format maybe because i have changed the value of the JSON so may have some mistake on it.

Below is the final log i get:

> 74/com.appandus.user.konnect I/Keykeykey: AccessTokens 07-12
>   17:14:38.177 6274-6274/com.appandus.user.konnect I/c1111: XXXXX 07-12
>   17:14:38.177 6274-6274/com.appandus.user.konnect I/c222222: BABABA
>   07-12 17:14:38.177 6274-6274/com.appandus.user.konnect I/c1111: NS/NH
>   : DIDAIDA 07-12 17:14:38.177 6274-6274/com.appandus.user.konnect
>   I/c222222: YYYYYY